# Allow validation for only one of the button in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a Login page using MVC Razor. The page contains a User name & Password to be entered and two button Login and SignUp button.

I have applied required field validation for both textboxes. It works fine when i click Login button. For Signup button i want the page to be redirected to signup page. But when i click SignUp button, it throws error as UserName and Password are required.

How to check for validation when only login button is clicked.

View page:

```
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckLogin", "Login"))
    {
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="@Url.Content("../../Content/Images/Logo.png")" alt="logo" style="margin-top:17px;" />@*width="184" height="171"*@
            </div>
            <div class="LoginBg">
                <h3 class="LoginHdng">
                    @Html.Label("lblLogin", "Login")
                </h3>
                <table style="width: 745px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 20px; text-align: right; width: 250px">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "User Name: ")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "txtBox" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 20px; text-align: right;">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, "Password: ")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "txtBox" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: Red;">
                            <br />
                            @TempData["Error"]
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Command" class="loginBtn" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <input type="submit" value="SignUp" name="Command" class="loginBtn" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckLogin(FormCollection coll)//, string command
        {
            if (coll["Command"] == "Login")
            {
                using (var db = new MVC_DBEntities())
                {
                    if (db.tbl_UserDetails.ToList().Select(m => m.FirstName == coll["FirstName"] && m.Password == coll["Password"]).FirstOrDefault())
                    {
                        TempData["Error"] = "";
                        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["Error"] = "Invalid UserName/Password";
                        return this.RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coll["Command"] == "SignUp")
            {
                return this.RedirectToAction("SignUp", "SignUp");
            }
            else
            {
                return this.RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Try to put debug point  in else if (coll["Command"] == "SignUp") and check whether its reaching hear or not?

Answer (score 1):

Take `Signup` button as **input type button** not **input type submit** as shown :-

```
<input type="button" value="SignUp" name="Command" class="loginBtn" id="SignUpBtn" />
```

and use some **Jquery/Javascript** to go to `SignUp Page` as :-

```
$("#SignUpBtn").click(function(){
   window.location.href="/SignUp/SignUp";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I have changed the type to button for SignUp button. Now the button click does nothing. Do i have to add a separate controller function for this button.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. A simple and perfect answer that fit my needs.. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a cancel class to the button that does not need the validation as follows:

```
<input type="submit" value="SignUp" name="Command" class="loginBtn cancel" />
```

This will circumvent validation, provided you are using the built in jQuery unobtrusive validation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

1. Can't you put "SignUp" as link and use css to appear like button.
2. wrap "SingUp" button around a separate form

```
<form action="/signup" method="get">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

1. Or As suggested use button with value property. u can use js to redirect or in controller u can look for value and redirect.